# R/quantmod: multiple charts all using the same y-axis

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

I'm trying to plot 6 days of intraday data as 6 charts. Quantmod's experimental chart_Series() function works with par() settings. I've pre-loaded the data into `bars` (a vector of XTS objects) so my code looks like this:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))   #3 rows, 2 columns

for(d in bars){
    print(chart_Series(d, type = "candlesticks") )
    }
```

This works, but each chart has its own different y-axis scale. I wanted to set a y-range that covers all 6 days, but cannot find a way to do this. I tried this:

```
ylim=c(18000,20000)
print(chart_Series(d, type = "candlesticks",ylim=ylim) )
```

but it fails with the "unused argument(s)" error. yrange=ylim also fails.

I can use chartSeries(d,yrange=ylim), and it works. But as far as I know I cannot put multiple charts in one display (?).
(It might strictly be off-subject, but suggestions for alternative R packages that can draw nice-looking candlestick charts, allow y-axis control and can draw multiple charts on one image would also be very welcome.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `chartSeries`, you can set the `layout` argument to `NULL` to prevent the `layout()` command from being called: this is what disables the `mfrow` setting.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AA")

op <- par(mfrow=c(3,2))
for(i in 1:6) {
  chartSeries(
    AA["2011-01"], "candlesticks", 
    TA=NULL, # No volume plot
    layout=NULL, 
    yrange=c(15,18)
  )
}
par(op)
```

If you want to keep the volume, you can call `layout` instead of setting `mfrow`: it does basically the same thing, but allows you to have plots of different sizes and choose the order in which they are plotted.

```
layout( matrix( c(
    1, 3,
    2, 4,
    5, 7,
    6, 8,
    9, 11,
   10, 12
  ), nc=2, byrow=TRUE),
  heights = rep( c(2,1), 3 )
)
#layout.show(12) # To check that the order is as desired
for(i in 1:6) {
  chartSeries( 
    AA[sprintf("2011-%02d",i)], 
    "candlesticks", layout=NULL, yrange=c(15,19) 
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, that works! Any suggestions/links/articles on how to use layout to bring back the volume sub-chart?

Comment: I have added an example with `layout` (before seeing your answer...)

Answer (score 2):

Googling to understand Vincent's answer led me to the layout() command. It seems incompatible with par(mfrow), but some more experimentation found it can be used *as an alternative*.

```
ylim=c(18000,20000)
layout(matrix(1:12,nrow=6,ncol=2), height=c(4,2,4,2,4,2))
for(d in bars){
    chartSeries(d,layout=NULL,TA=c(addVo(),addBBands()),yrange=ylim)
    }
```

(You'll notice I added bollinger bands too, to be sure overlays still work too.)